# Code works if request returns multiple objects, error if request returns only one

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to fetch candidates depending on what industry they work in. My request returns this data when I send a request for candidates in an industry where there's only one (it's in JSON):

```
 stdClass Object ([Candidates] => stdClass Object ([row] =>
 stdClass Object ([no] => 1 [FL] => Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [content] => 213748000001275022 [val] => RESUMEID ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [content] => John (3) [val] => Modified by ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [content] => 11 Aug-2015 [val] => Modified time ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [content] => 3308 [val] => Candidate ID ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [content] => John (3) [val] => Recruiter ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [content] => Creative arts [val] => Branche / Industry ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [content] => Ja / Yes [val] => Accept af optagelse i Kandidatbank / Accept my registration in
 candidatedatabase )))))
```

I use this code:

```
$rowArray = $data->response->result->Candidates->row;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($rowArray); $i++) {            

      $FL = $data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL;

}
```

The exact error I'm getting is that I "cannot use object of type stdClass as array", but why this error now? I works totally fine on other requests. To explain things a little further with some code, here's what `$FL` is used for:

```
if (array_key_exists(4, $FL) === true && $FL[4]->val === 'Branche / Industry') {
      $industry = $FL[4]->content;
} else if (array_key_exists(5, $FL) === true && $FL[5]->val === 'Branche / Industry') {
      $industry = $FL[5]->content;
} else {
      $industry = $notSpecified;
}
```

It sets the variables of the candidate in my PHP code so I can present it in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could proceed as follows  -
 1. First check if it is an array then do as usual
 2. Else create an array and push it then do as usual

```
$rowArray = $data->response->result->Candidates->row;
        if(!is_array($rowArray))
        {
        $rowArray=array($data->response->result->Candidates->row);
        //so that $rowArray is now an array and count gives 1
        }
```

Comment: I ended up implementing a solution basically identical to this one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$FL = $data->response->result->Candidates->row->FL[$i];
```

It's telling you "cannot use object of type stdClass as array" because you are trying to do just that; access an object as if it were an array.  Maybe your server is returning a different data structure based on the specific request you send it.